# Has there been any changes to Paypal's IPN in the last month?

Tags: php, paypal, wordpress, paypal-ipn

I'm using WMPU Dev Event+ plugin and it won't handle the IPN, or more specifically it tells me its an "Invalid PayPal IPN" when I stub email calls through there process_paypal_ipn() and return an appropriate message the set.  Anyone else have IPN handling issues recently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was an issue with the plugin that was introduced early in the year with an update.  WMPU Dev has produced a patch for this issue as of today.

Answer (score 1):

I have not but I would contact PayPal's MTS team by phone or contact them through paypal.com/mts